# How to search at element's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
if($('span').text().indexOf("t")){
  console.log($('span').text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>six</span>
```

The result should be just `three` and `two` in console. Because just they contain `t` letter.  But as you see all values will be shown  in the console.

As I've mentioned, I'm trying to make a small search engine for a autocomplete box. How can I fix it?

Comment: The answer are all missing an explanation why your script won't do what you want it to do... The summary: `$("span")` gets every `<span>` element in the document, [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) returns the text of all matched elements combined as one string, [`.indexOf(searchValue)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1` if `searchValue` has not been found

Comment: @Andreas I see, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation `text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method returns a string containing the combined text of all matched elements that what it showing in your console, instead you need to iterate over them. Even though your condition is wrong, which only fails when the index is `0`(`0` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value and all other integer values are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in Javascript), it should be `.indexOf("t") > -1`.

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf("t") > -1)
    console.log($(this).text());
})

// or use text() method with callback which holds 
// old value as second argument and iterates internally
$('span').text(function(i, txt) {
  if (txt.indexOf("t") > -1)
    console.log(txt);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>six</span>
```

---

The simplest way is to use CSS [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-class selector and iterate over the elements using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```js
$('span:contains("t")').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>six</span>
```

---

**UPDATE :** You can use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method with [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method to get as an array.

```js
console.log($('span:contains("t")').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>six</span>
```

Comment: Hah .. two :-) ...! I believe you have some enemies.

Comment: @stack : may be there is :(

Comment: What's that question mark `?` in `.indexOf("t") ? > -1` ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan, +1 nice answer.

Comment: Great. Just what do you need `i` for? *(which you've passed in `text` function)*

Comment: @stack : it's index of the element, commonly everyone uses `_` for unused arguments.....

Comment: sorry to see down votes on a very detailed answer :) upvoted.

Comment: And my last question *(which isn't related to current question)*, can you please tell me what's `ev` which is passed in [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/mao84shw/)?

Comment: @stack : where ??? in event handler - then it would be event object .... it depends upon your code....

Comment: please open the fiddle I've linked in my previous comment and take a look at `keydown: function(ev) {` line  ..! What's `ev` ?

Comment: @stack :  which is the event object

Comment: nn buddy `.. ;-)`

Answer (score 4):

You can to use [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```js
$('span:contains("t")').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>six</span>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what's `item` you've passed it?

Comment: It's not necessary, I forgot it there :)

Comment: @stack, it returns the index of every element in the loop. In this particular case does not really matter as Lucas Costa said.

Answer (score 3):

`$('span')` selects all the span elements on the page. If you need to work with them individually, you need to loop over all the `span` elements and test the condition on individual items. You can use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function for this.

Also, [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1` if the string doesn't contain the argument, so you need to compare it with `-1`.

```js
$('span').each(function () {
  if($(this).text().indexOf("t") != -1){
     console.log($(this).text());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>six</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should loop through the elements and check the values using `>` operator:

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf("t") > -1) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>six</span>
```

You can read more about `each()` method **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**.

Comment: That will only find the ones that *begin* with "t"; `eight`, for example, wouldn't be returned.

Comment: @Shaggy, you're right, changed it accordingly. Now will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$('span').text() return linked text of every span in array, so you must iterate through span elements with for, or each (jQuery) method:

```
 $('span').each(function () {
    if($(this).text().indexOf("t") > 0){
        console.log($(this).text());
    }
 });

 var elems = $('span');
 for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
     if($(elems[i]).text().indexOf("t") > 0){
        console.log($(this).text());
    }
 }
```

Comment: "$('span').text() return just text of first span in array" *wrong*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. val() return just first value (I messed up), but solution is ok :) Edited...